# java derby connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused

Tags: java, database, jdbc, derby

I am trying to connect derby client database to my java project. At first everything was fine.After 3 days later Suddenly the derby db could not be connected.It's showing this message "Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused:"

Database connection code:

```
public Connection getConnection() {
    try {

        String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
        } catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String dbURL2 = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/D:/Java Project/Alo Art Academy/AloArtDB;create=true";
        String user = "HabibDB";
        String password = "habib2017";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL2, user, password);

        if (conn != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to database #2");
        }
        return conn;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then  edited C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77\lib\security
 the java.policy file and add the following permission

```
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1527", "listen";
```

but no luck! :(

stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused: connect.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at alo.art.academy.workstation.getConnection(workstation.java:46)
    at alo.art.academy.workstation.<init>(workstation.java:27)
    at alo.art.academy.AloArtAcademy$1.run(AloArtAcademy.java:26)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

What is wrong with me?

Comment: _Connection refused: connect._ means that nothing is listening on port 1527 on localhost; in other words: Derby is not running.

Comment: Were you using a tool like NetBeans or Eclipse to develop your project? A lot of such tools start the Derby Network Server automatically for you, but when you exit your IDE, the server also gets shut down. You can start the Derby Network Server by hand, or you can just restart your IDE while you're still developing your project.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem in your URL why you specify the exact path of your Database :

```
String dbURL2 = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/D:/Java Project/Alo Art Academy/AloArtDB;create=true";
```

The connection URL syntax is as follows:

```
jdbc:derby:[subsubprotocol:][databaseName][;attribute=value]*
```

So change your URL like this :

```
String dbURL2 = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/AloArtDB;create=true";
```

- Make sure that the post is open
- Make sure to download and put your [jdbc derby driver](https://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html) in class
  path.

You can learn more [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/derby_app.html) and [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.3/tools/ttoolsij97656.html)

Comment: At first i was using this:
String dbURL2 = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/AloArtDB;create=true";

but when i was facing problem i googled and read some post then i changed dbURL... but still dosent work :(

i added derby.jar, derbyclient.jar, derbyrun.jar, java db driver

Comment: Hey, I am in the middle of setting up the NetBeans with derby and I am getting this error when I try to create a new connection.
`Connection failed: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused). (jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample;create=true using org.apche.derby.client.ClientAutoloadedDriver)`